# How to do the below task in shell script using grep but without a for loop?

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, grep

I have a file, say A.txt, which has roughly around 80,000 lines but 2 fields. Example lines look like below:

```
utt1 f 
utt2 f 
utt3 m 
utt4 f
```

I have a second file B.txt, which has more way more lines than A.txt and  has two fields. Example lines look like below

```
utt1_1 somethingHere    
utt1_2 somethingElse    
utt2_1 someText    
utt2_2 somemore    
utt2_3 someMore    
utt3_1 someText    
utt4_1 somemore    
utt4_2 abcd    
utt4_3 aanan
```

The first field in B.txt is basically the same as first field in A.txt followed by _something (Each line is repeated variable number of times).

My task is to make a file which looks like this

```
utt1_1 f    
utt1_2 f    
utt2_1 f    
utt2_2 f    
utt2_3 f    
utt3_1 m    
utt4_1 f    
utt4_2 f    
utt4_3 f
```

'f' and 'm' starts for gender. in other words what I want to do is get utt and gender information from A.txt and grep for the utterance in B.txt and map the first field with the right gender. I am doing it using a while loop as follows:

```
while read utt gen; do
   grep $utt B.txt | awk -v gen=$gen '{print $1" "gen}'
done < A.txt
```

Since, I am doing it in a loop and length of A.txt is big it is taking a lot of time to complete the task. Could you suggest me a faster way to do it using bash?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to do it with bash/awk etc? You tagged the question with python, so...

Comment: python or bash without having to write a separate script. I just want to get it done within one or two lines. This would be a subtask within a big shell script that already have

Comment: @Inian it actually looks like that

Answer (score 5):

This is tailor made job for `awk` 2 file processing:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1] = $2; next} $1 in a {print $1 "_" $2, a[$1]}' file1 FS='[_ ]' file2
utt1_1 f
utt1_2 f
utt2_1 f
utt2_2 f
utt2_3 f
utt3_1 m
utt4_1 f
utt4_2 f
utt4_3 f
```

Arguments `file1 FS='[_ ]' file2` set input field separator `_` or space for `file2` only.

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk, this time using `split`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{split($1,b,"_");if(i=b[1] in a)print $1,a[b[1]]}' file1 file2
utt1_1 f
utt1_2 f
utt2_1 f
utt2_2 f
utt2_3 f
utt3_1 m
utt4_1 f
utt4_2 f
utt4_3 f
```

Explained:

```
NR==FNR {                   # process the first file
    a[$1]=$2                # hash it to a hash with $2 as value
    next }                  # move to next record
{                           # process the second (or any number of) file
    split($1,b,"_")         # split the $1 on _ 
    if(i=b[1] in a)         # first part of b is the key to hash
        print $1,a[b[1]] }  # output $1 and hash value
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 !~ /_/ { lst[$1]=$2 } $1 ~ /_/ { print $1" "lst[substr($1,1,4)] }' file1 file2
```

If the file contain fields that don't pattern matched with _ then add them to an array, else print the first string in each file along with the value in the array we have created.